# How do I approach to solve this partial derivative

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

Find $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial x}$ where $M = \dfrac{3}{x^3}\displaystyle\int_0^Nz(x,y)x^2 dx$
and $z(x,y)$ satisfies $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \alpha(\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} +\dfrac{2}{x}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x})$, as well as $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}(0,y) = 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}(N,y) = \beta$ are given as 0 and $\beta$. Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants.

I haven't dealt with partial derivatives and this math in a long time and I don't understand how to proceed further. Can someone point me to a direction on how can I solve this?

Comment: I have edited the question, please check I have not changed the meaning. Please also include whatever attempts you have tried.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing. I'm a returning Masters student and I do have to say I lost touch with Calculus. I'm not exactly looking for a straight-up answer, but more of how can I solve this derivative, it's a part of an assignment problem that I'm doing. I'm stuck thinking do I need to take the 3/x^3 term into the integral and then proceed to solve the problem? OR solve the partial derivative of z first and substitute that into M and then expand using chain rule?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_a^b f(t, x) \mathrm{d}t = \int_a^b \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (t, x) \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Yes, That's what I was trying to do too! But how do I deal with 3/x^3 term? How can I pull that into the integral first? The z is also a function of x.

Comment: How about treating the $3/x^3$ and the integral as two separate terms; apply the product rule

Comment: In fact... note that the integral is over $x$,  but we can use any dummy variable, say $w$ instead. What does that tell you?

Comment: Hm. Taking $w =x^-2$? Then the $1/x^3$ outside can be expressed as the derivative of w. Is that useful?

Comment: I dunno if this is unrelated, but do I need to solve the $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ first? Cuz even if I treat the $1/x^3$ term as separate and try to solve it, the condition is given as a partial derivative of y. Should I try to get an expression in terms of the partial derivative of x first?